# Crontab unable to open google chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, cron

I have written a chrome extension that performs a task whenever it is available, and for that I would need the chrome browser open at all times. My idea was to have a check say every minute if the google process is running if not start chrome. I have added the following in my users crontab (I'm running Ubuntu 14.04)

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && if ! ps aux | grep -q "[c]hrome"; then google-chrome; fi
```

However nothing seems to run, did i miss out on anything?

Answer (score 2):

The enviroment that you get for a cronjob is very limited. For example, you don't get the DISPLAY variable which is required to open chrome.

Instead of `google-chrome` use `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this kind of user-crontab entry is that it needs bash to be able to run.

So the easiest way is to create a small bash-script like `/home/dylanfa88/keep-chrome-running` and put this in your user-crontab.

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/dylanfa88/keep-chrome-running
```